# Efficient way to merge-sort data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, sorting

I have a series of tables that contain data of similar format. I.e. a `UNION` would work. 
Conceptually you can think of it as 1 table partitioned into multiple tables. 
I want to get the data from all of these tables sorted.
Now the problem I have is that the data are too much to be displayed all at once to the user, so I need to display them in portions i.e. pages.
Now my problem is that I need to display the data sorted (as already said).

So if I do something like:

```
SELECT FROM TABLE_1  
UNION  
SELECT FROM TABLE_2  
UNION  
....  
SELECT FROM TABLE_N
ORDER BY COL  
LIMIT OFFSET, RECORDS;
```

I would constantly be doing a `UNION` and `ORDER BY` to get e.g. the just the corresponding 50 records of the pages on each request.

So how would I most efficiently handle this?

Comment: Can you SELECT the data INTO a temp table and then add a column for page number or something?

Comment: @DavidStarkey:So create something like a look-up table?

Comment: @DavidStarkey:What would be the flow for this?At the application level if there is no such temp table I create one and then use it for requests? Or some other way?

Comment: do some research on "Pagination".

Comment: There are a few options, easiest would probably be a nightly update process for this table.

Comment: @DavidStarkey:Are you refereing to the DB level? Some kind of trigger?

Comment: I have something like this set up for a monthly report.  Basically, I made an ASP page (but really you could just use a Stored Procedure or whatever you want that can run a SQL line) that would populate this table with the most recent data.  Then I made a Scheduled Task (Google it if you need to) that runs every night at 11PM, which means every day I will have a Table that is up-to-date as of 11PM the day before.  How up-to-date does this information need to be?

Comment: @DavidStarkey:Actually part of the information in the tables is a timestamp and the user will choose a date *before* doing the `order by`. So essentially I would need to sort and page over the time/date period selected by the user.

Comment: If all the data is in a pre-generated table, then your SELECT can include that range when they request the page.  If you index properly, then the request should be fast enough.

Comment: @DavidStarkey:The data are not static of course.The original tables are being updated in quite frequent intervals.So this look-up pregenerated table would need to be updated as well. But in this case, we might have not kept the tables separated in the first place since the lookup table would now contain all the data aggregated as well.Am I misunderstanding your solution? What do you think on this?

Comment: The new table would only need to contain relevant data.  Depending on how the data is sorted, you could add on new entries to the bottom of the table (`WHERE newTable.MAX(timestamp)<otherTables.Timestamp`) and this would ensure that you have all the data without having to go through everything each time.  This really all depends on how fast your query is going.  If the query you offered runs quickly, then every time the data is requested, make a temp table (sorted as you want it) and SELECT from it where ID is between the proper values (1-50, 51-100, etc).

Comment: @DavidStarkey:Kind of lost you on your last comment.`The new table would only need to contain relevant data`. What do you mean?Relevant to what?The user could give any search range to search over the tables. So *all* the data in all the tables are potential match for each user query.

Comment: Depends on you table structure and what you are displaying to the user.  Say you are using a user table with columns for ID, name, phone, email, show size, and Timestamp.  If this page only needs Names and Shoe Sizes, then you can leave out irrelevant things like phone and email.

Comment: @DavidStarkey:I see what you mean.Yes this makes a lot of sense but unfortunatelly I am displaying all columns

Comment: You could also use a binary search to narrow down the records in each table.

Comment: Is this not that case when spinx\elasticsearch could give a help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first attempt would be UNION'ing just a small number of records from each table:

```sql
( SELECT FROM table_1 ORDER BY col LIMIT @offset, @records )
UNION  
...  
( SELECT FROM table_N ORDER BY col LIMIT @offset, @records )
ORDER BY col LIMIT @offset, @records
```

If the above proves insufficient, I would build a manual index table (based on David Starkey's clever suggestion).

```
CREATE TABLE index_table (
    table_id INT,
    item_id INT,
    col DATETIME,
    INDEX (col, table_id, id)
);
```

Then populate `index_table` with a method of your liking (cron job, triggers on tables `table_n`, ...). Your `SELECT` statement would then look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT * FROM index_table ORDER BY col LIMIT @offset, @records ) AS idx
LEFT JOIN table_1 ON (idx.table_id = 1 AND idx.item_id = table_1.id)
...
LEFT JOIN table_n ON (idx.table_id = n AND idx.item_id = table_n.id)
```

However, I am not sure of how such a query would perform with so many LEFT JOIN's. It really depends on how many tables `table_n` there are.

Finally, I would consider merging all tables into one single table.

Comment: Have you any ideas whether it makes sense to use sphinx/solr/elasticsearch ? Merging table to one is not a option in my case (tables are huge and have different structure), creating temporary tables too , because data are updated every ten seconds (or more often). Just interesting to hear your opinion

Comment: I suppose it would make sense, but I can't advise. Consider asking this as a question, and link to this question for context.